# CSS3 file 404 - - Node.JS and EJS

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, ejs

I know this seems to be a duplicate but I've looked at other answers but they won't work for me. Here's my code:

NodeJs:

```
var express = require("express"),
    app     = express(),
    mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/e_c");

app.use(express.static(__dirname+"public"));
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"partials"));

var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  author: String,
  pictureForTitle: String,
  content: String
});

var blog = mongoose.model("blog",blogSchema);

app.set("view engine","ejs");

  app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.render("home");
  });

  app.listen(process.env.PORT,process.env.IP);
```

Head.ejs:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<nav id="navBar">
    <div id="aboutSite">
        <p>About This Site</p>
        <div id="aSDropContent">
            <p>About The Author Of This Site</p>
            <p>Why The Author Created This</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I've tried the express.static, as you can see. But it doesn't work. I even tried copying/look from/at a previous project.

Thanks a ton,
Josh C.

Comment: Does your CSS file exist at `[ROOT]/public/css/styles.css`? If not, you may be looking for a **relative** URL: `href="public/css/styles.css"`.

Comment: Yes, of course! I checked multiple times. Thanks, though.

Comment: Does it work if you change the href to `"css/styles.css"` by any chance? If it still doesn't, then remove `app.use(express.static(__dirname+"partials"));` and only leave `app.use(express.static(__dirname+"public"));` and try again.

Comment: Tried both, but they didn't work. Thanks, though.

Comment: If html is loading properly, then try using href="./public/css/styles.css" dot in front of the URL to denote the current directory

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue and fixed it by replacing "**public**" with "**/public**"

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/public"));
```

and

```
href="/css/styles.css"
```